# KeyListener does not work, but Mousepressed does

Tags: java, user-interface, io, keylistener, keyevent

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
public class StateController extends GraphicsProgram {

    public Menu menu = new Menu();

    public void run() {
        addMouseListeners();
        addKeyListeners();
    }

}

public class Menu {
    int x = 0;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MousEvent e) {
       System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

The program detects when the mouse is pressed, but it does not print X when a key is. Can you see any problems?

Thank very much.

Comment: Please, post a short but complete example of what you are doing. The code you posted makes no sense, so it's impossible for us to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: `Here is a simplified version of my code` - a simplified version doesn't really help us. The problem may be in the code you decided not to include. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you add listeners to your class, this class has to implement the listener interfaces in order to get the notifications:

```
public class StateController extends GraphicsProgram implements MouseListener, KeyListener
```

Or you do it on-the-fly:

```
yourUiElement.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}         
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}          
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code actually compiles and you implemented the KeyListener interface correctly, KeyEvents are only dispatched to components that have focus. Your StateController doesn't have focus.

By default a JPanel is not focusable. So I'm guessing your StateController class is extending JPanel. So you need to:

1. Make the panel focusable by using `setFocusable(true)` in the constructor of your class
2. Invoke `panel.requestFocusInWindow()` AFTER the GUI has been made visible. You can only request focus on a component in a visible GUI.